# How can I edit /etc/skel while keeping the default folders on Live CD

Tags: skel

I'm making a Live CD with all of the features I need in Ubuntu. I've installed gnome-shell and some extensions and I want to make it start "ON" when the instalation finishes.

I've copied the folders ".config/" and ".gconf/" to "/etc/skel/" after configuring my default user, but every time I install Ubuntu, after that I can't find the default folders (desktop, public, videos, music...).

I've tried everything I knew, does someone know how I can do what I'm trying to?

(Sorry about my bad english, i'm a Brazilian guy)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, but the folders were with wrong permissions, just change it by using `sudo chmod -R 755 /etc/skel/.config /etc/skel/.gconf` and it works fine.